# Monitor the number of not leased yet IP address in Window DHCP Server with Nagios in Linux

Tags: dhcp, nagios, ip-address

Sometimes, the IP address are used up and they don't change their state letting the server to allocate all address.

How to use Nagios to monitor the number of not leased yet ip address in pool in window DHCP Server?

Is there any plugin or service in nagios in linux that can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `dhcpd-pools`: http://dhcpd-pools.sourceforge.net/

The documentation doesn't reference it directly, but it has Nagios compatible output mode (since v2.19) and the `contrib/` subdirectory of the package has the check command fragment to get you started.

Comment: actually DHCP server is window DHCP Server but Nagios is installed in Linux

Comment: A rather important consideration which might kick this problem into the superuser.SE domain ... Check https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Operating-Systems/Windows there are at least two plugins for Windows DHCP listed there.

Comment: how to use user interface of nagios to add these vb script  to run for a host?

Comment: i use admin , manage plugin and upload plugin , then define command, but discover check dhcp free.vbs, use  cscript.exe -T:120 -NoLogo scripts\check_dhcp_free.vbs need subnet as parameter, it seems need to define many commands for each subnet then for example, 3 subnet , will have 3 services using 3 commands respectively, is it correct?